# How to read files inside a folder in Drive inside a notebook

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I want to read the dataset from drive inside Google Colab Notbook.
how can I do that?
I did something like this but it's not working.

```
train_data_dir = "data/train/"
validation_data_dir = "data/validation/"
```

[image: This is the structure of my project]

The data folder is like this:

```
data/
    train/
        dogs/
            dog001.jpg
            dog002.jpg
            ...
        cats/
            cat001.jpg
            cat002.jpg
            ...
    validation/
        dogs/
            dog001.jpg
            dog002.jpg
            ...
        cats/
            cat001.jpg
            cat002.jpg
            ...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution using the [Drive FUSE wrapper](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q#scrollTo=Q0u3VR-gmbF4)

you have to install the drive fuse wrapper then make a directory then mount it, that directory is the root directory of your drive, upload your dataset to your google drive and access it using "/content/name_of_your_directory/dataset_name/"

in my case I followed these steps:

### 1-Install a Drive FUSE wrapper.

```
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
```

then

### 2-Generate auth tokens for Colab

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

### 3-Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
```

### 4-Work around misordering of STREAM and STDIN in Jupyter.

```
prompt = !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass(prompt[0] + '\n\nEnter verification code: ')
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

### 5-Create a directory and mount Google Drive using that directory.

```
!mkdir -p yourdirectory
!google-drive-ocamlfuse yourdirectory
```

#### 6- access this directory from code like in my case

```
train_data_dir = "/content/yourdirectory/data/train/"
validation_data_dir = "/content/yourdirectory/data/validation/"
```