# Stuck in datalab directory, can't navigate to my desired directory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a directory named ML in my drive: which has some of my colab-notebooks and some csv files which I want to load in my colab-notebook.

But , when I use !pwd to find out the current folder, its output is as follows.

```
!pwd
/content
```

When I use !ls .. The directory structure is as follows:

```
bin/
boot/
colabtools/
content/
datalab/
dev/
etc/
gpu-tensorflow-1.9.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gpu-tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
home/
lib/
lib64/
media/
mnt/
opt/
proc/
root/
run/
sbin/
srv/
sys/
tensorflow-1.9.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
tf_deps/
tmp/
tools/
usr/
var/
```

I am unable to !cd to my directory which is drive/ML , since I don't know the path, and the tree structure and thus, load my csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In such cases we need to mount our google-drive and it will be shown as
>   below:

```
os.listdir()
/content
```

And,

```
os.listdir('/content')

datalab  drive
```

If the google-drive isn't mounted the /content directory will only contain the datalab folder.

> To mount your Google Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

For further information refer [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-tensorflow-keras-pytorch.html)

Afterwards, to change directory use:

```
import os
os.chdir("drive/My Drive/ML")
```

Answer (score 3):

use `%cd` instead of `!cd`, like this:

```
%cd drive/ML
```

Comment: I get this error, I'm in the /content directory [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive/ML'
/content

Comment: The directory is not your google drive. You need to map it first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606118/how-to-read-files-inside-a-folder-in-drive-inside-a-notebook

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out now, my-google drive wasn't mounted in the first place and so, I didn't get a directory for my drive in the /contents directory. Thanks a lot.